# Data displayed incoherently in Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I am having some problem trying to pull data from the below `link` and have it display in a DataFrame properly.

The below code gives me what I want, but I think because there are a couple of `tables` within the link that has the same `class` name: `ReutersTabInit`, the results that are returned into the DataFrame is kinda messed up.

```
link = r'http://www.4-traders.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/financials/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).text, 'html.parser')
pandas_1 = pd.read_html(link, flavor='bs4', header=0, index_col=0, 
                        attrs={'class': "ReutersTabInit"}, encoding='utf8')
```

**Result of code**

```
[                            2016e       2017e
Size                                         
Capitalization         380 864 M$           -
Entreprise Value (EV)  331 350 M$  322 831 M$,                               2016e  2017e
Valuation                                 
P/E ratio (Price / EPS)       17,5x  15,3x
Capitalization / Revenue      4,14x  3,86x
EV / Revenue                  3,60x  3,27x
EV / EBITDA                   9,82x  8,91x
Yield (DPS / Price)           2,74%  3,02%
Price to book (Price / BVPS)  4,56x  3,99x,                                                2016e  2017e
Profitability                                              
Operating Margin (EBIT / Sales)                31,0%  32,1%
operating Leverage (Delta EBIT / Delta Sales)      -  1,55x
Net Margin (Net Profit / Revenue)              23,7%  24,5%
ROA (Net Profit / Asset)                       11,7%  13,1%
ROE (Net Profit / Equities)                    24,8%  26,5%
Rate of Dividend                               48,0%  46,4%,                                              2016e   2017e
Balance Sheet Analysis                                    
CAPEX / Sales                                6,52%   6,39%
Cash Flow / Sales (Taux d'autofinancement)   32,4%   34,5%
Capital Intensity (Assets / Sales)           2,03x   1,87x
Financial Leverage (Net Debt / EBITDA)      -1,47x  -1,60x]
```

As you can see, the format goes all over the place. I'm trying to get it to be displayed as such.

**Desired Result**

```
                         2016e       2017e
Size                                         
Capitalization         380 864 M$           -
Entreprise Value (EV)  331 350 M$  322 831 M$,                               

                               2016e  2017e
Valuation                                 
P/E ratio (Price / EPS)       17,5x  15,3x
Capitalization / Revenue      4,14x  3,86x
EV / Revenue                  3,60x  3,27x
EV / EBITDA                   9,82x  8,91x
Yield (DPS / Price)           2,74%  3,02%
Price to book (Price / BVPS)  4,56x  3,99x,                                                

                                                2016e  2017e
Profitability                                              
Operating Margin (EBIT / Sales)                31,0%  32,1%
operating Leverage (Delta EBIT / Delta Sales)      -  1,55x
Net Margin (Net Profit / Revenue)              23,7%  24,5%
ROA (Net Profit / Asset)                       11,7%  13,1%
ROE (Net Profit / Equities)                    24,8%  26,5%
Rate of Dividend                               48,0%  46,4%,                                              

                                              2016e   2017e
Balance Sheet Analysis                                    
CAPEX / Sales                                6,52%   6,39%
Cash Flow / Sales (Taux d'autofinancement)   32,4%   34,5%
Capital Intensity (Assets / Sales)           2,03x   1,87x
Financial Leverage (Net Debt / EBITDA)      -1,47x  -1,60x]
```

Which is the same as how its displayed on the website.

Anyone has any idea how I can format it to show each table, in different DataFrames, or each table in the same DataFrame, but formatted the same way as the website?

Comment: Could you provide us with the example of the output and clearer explanation of what does not work and what is the desired result?

Comment: @pausag I've added in the the desired result and more information about the problem i'm having. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pd.read_html gives back a list of DataFrames, and so when you print pandas_1 out, it's not aligning things nicely. Just print one of them at a time and they'll look more like what you're expecting.

```
In [30]: for df in pandas_1:
   ....:     print df
   ....:     print
   ....:
                            2016e       2017e
Size
Capitalization         380 864 M$           -
Entreprise Value (EV)  331 350 M$  322 831 M$

                              2016e  2017e
Valuation
P/E ratio (Price / EPS)       17,5x  15,3x
Capitalization / Revenue      4,14x  3,86x
EV / Revenue                  3,60x  3,27x
EV / EBITDA                   9,82x  8,91x
Yield (DPS / Price)           2,74%  3,02%
Price to book (Price / BVPS)  4,56x  3,99x

                                               2016e  2017e
Profitability
Operating Margin (EBIT / Sales)                31,0%  32,1%
operating Leverage (Delta EBIT / Delta Sales)      -  1,55x
Net Margin (Net Profit / Revenue)              23,7%  24,5%
ROA (Net Profit / Asset)                       11,7%  13,1%
ROE (Net Profit / Equities)                    24,8%  26,5%
Rate of Dividend                               48,0%  46,4%

                                             2016e   2017e
Balance Sheet Analysis
CAPEX / Sales                                6,52%   6,39%
Cash Flow / Sales (Taux d'autofinancement)   32,4%   34,5%
Capital Intensity (Assets / Sales)           2,03x   1,87x
Financial Leverage (Net Debt / EBITDA)      -1,47x  -1,60x
```

Comment: Thanks Randy. So simple, but it didn't occur to me. :)